# Trajectory Plot inside of 3D transparent sphere using R

Tags: r, plot, transparency, rgl

I want to make a trajectory plot of my `df` inside of a transparent 3d sphere.

I searched the stackoverflow but couldn't find the same question. So it might be helpful for everybody who is interested about trajectory of their vectors.

The `df` could be like this

```
df <- data.frame(mx=runif(100,-0.05,0.05),
             my=runif(100,-1,1),
             mz=runif(100,-0.5,0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Frank's answer. If what you want to do is to plot trajectories on a sphere like the supplied picture, you should be a bit more careful, since ordinary interpolation won't give paths on the sphere. There are different options, but the easiest is probably to just project the paths onto the sphere.

```
require(rgl)

# Construct a Brownian motion on a sphere
n <- 100
sigma <- 0.5

df <- array(NA, dim = c(n, 3))
df[1, ] <- rnorm(3, sd = sigma) # Starting point
df[1, ] <- df[1, ] / sqrt(sum(df[1, ]^2))
for (i in 2:n) {
  df[i, ] <- rnorm(3, sd = sigma) + df[i - 1, ]
  df[i, ] <- df[i, ] / sqrt(sum(df[i, ]^2))
}

# Linear interpolation of observed trajectories, but projected onto sphere
times <- seq(1, n, length = 1000)

xx <- approx(1:n, df[, 1], xout = times)$y
yy <- approx(1:n, df[, 2], xout = times)$y
zz <- approx(1:n, df[, 3], xout = times)$y
df_proj <- cbind(xx, yy, zz)
df_proj <- df_proj / sqrt(rowSums(df_proj ^2))

# Plot
plot3d(df_proj, type = 'l', col = heat.colors(1000), lwd = 2, xlab = 'x', ylab = 'y', zlab = 'z')
rgl.spheres(0, 0, 0, radius = 0.99, col = 'red', alpha = 0.6, back = 'lines')
```

[image: trajectories on sphere]

You can of course do the same thing with the smooth trajectories from Frank's answer:

```
# Smooth trajectories plot

times <- seq(1, n, length = 1000)
xx <- spline(1:n, df[, 1], xout = times)$y
yy <- spline(1:n, df[, 2], xout = times)$y
zz <- spline(1:n, df[, 3], xout = times)$y

df_smooth <- cbind(xx, yy, zz)
df_smooth <- df_smooth / sqrt(rowSums(df_smooth^2))

plot3d(df_smooth, type = 'l', col = heat.colors(1000), lwd = 2, xlab = 'x', ylab = 'y', zlab = 'z')
rgl.spheres(0, 0, 0, radius = 0.99, col = 'red', alpha = 0.6, back = 'lines')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can connect the points inside the sphere using `type="l"` in `plot3d` and plot the sphere using `spheres3d`:

```
library(rgl)
plot3d(df, type="l", axes=FALSE) # type="l" is for "line"
spheres3d(0,0,0, radius=1, alpha=0.3, back="cull") # transparency set by alpha from 0 to 1
```

[image]

Or to use splines to make a "smooth" trajectory, taking from [Duncan Murdoch](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-November/179848.html):

```
xx <- splinefun(seq_along(df$mx), df$mx)
yy <- splinefun(seq_along(df$my), df$my)
zz <- splinefun(seq_along(df$mz), df$mz)
times<-seq(1, dim(df)[1], len=2000) # vary length to change smoothness

plot3d(xx(times), yy(times), zz(times), type="l", axes=FALSE) 
spheres3d(0,0,0, radius=1, alpha=0.3, back="cull")
```

[image]

As you can see, this way, you *may* end up with a line outside of the radius of 1, so you can simply increase the radius of the sphere either by entering a larger number for radius or by using `radius=max(xx(times), yy(times), zz(times))`